# Extract HTML based WebCalculator to Excel

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

There are lot of solutions to convert **Excel Calculators** to **HTML** and host them.

But is there a way to re-engineer a HTML based Web calculator to Excel with all the Formulas and Calculation to understand the Calculation approach

Please guide

Comment: In order to remake it in Excel you'd first have to figure out how the HTML version works, so you're not going to learn anything from the Excel version itself.

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for your response. I understand how the Web version works. Let say for example I need to input 3 different values in the text box and say calculate. What it does is based on 3 values provided it is doing certain calculations at the backend and throwing up a result. Want to understand how the 3 inputs are used to decipher the output. It  input is looking up a table at the backend and doing a best fit method and giving back the result

Comment: To simply put. I want to under how this site works (http://www.dresssizecalculator.com/)

Comment: if calculations are occurring on the server there may be no way to tell exactly what's going on there. If on the client then you can look at the script to see what it does.

Comment: I agree. But if you refer the link i sent in my previous message and lookup the Source, calculations are happening in the Client and the Array is defined

Comment: So - start there?  I'm not sure anyone is going to do that for you.  That's a big mess of script to untangle.

Comment: Sure let we work in the direction suggested and see how it results